# Shortcut to the Soul Cairn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

Geting to the Soul Cairn the first time took a LOT of dungeon crawling.  Aside from the lack of enemies, getting out didn't seem any easier than getting in.

I've got some side-quests left to complete in the Soul Cairn, but am dreading having to go through all that dungeon again just to get there.  Is there a shortcut, or a fast-travel location I missed along the way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Dawnguard main questline [Chasing Echoes](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Chasing_Echoes), after you reached Valerica's Study (where the portal to Soul Cairn located) you will find another door labeled `Castle Volkihar Balcony`. Exit through there and you will get a quick fast travel location for Valerica's Study in the world map.

Comment: Aw, crap.  So, this means I have to take the long way back at least one more time?

Comment: [20 minutes later...]  Wow.  Looks like there really was no other way.  Almost can't believe they made a dead-end balcony for the sole purpose of putting a fast-travel location there.

Comment: @Iszi lol I did almost the exact same thing you did

Answer (score 1):

Become ethereal, when you have stepped out of Valericas study and onto the balcony of course, and take that plunge. If you have Dragonborn dlc, in order to get back faster, summon a dragon ie durnehviir or odahviing, bend will, and boom head up past icewater jetty and BAM!